# jquery.post() value always gets fail

Tags: jquery, post, laravel-5

am new to laravel so please consider that.here when i use jquery.post method i always gets result as fails and i dont know why will it be a problem of route or not here is my code please have a look

```
<script>
$(".fa-exchange").click(function(){
  var doctor_id=$(this).attr('doctorid');
  $("#doctor_id").val(doctor_id);
  var status=$(this).attr('status');
  $("#status").val(status);
        });
  $("#change-ok").click(function(){

            var doctor_id=$("#doctor_id").val();
            var status=$("#status").val();
            var url='{{url('/change-doctor-status/')}}';

            $.post(url, {doctor_id:doctor_id,status:status }).done(function (result) {
               alert("success");
            }).fail(function(result) {
              alert("There was an error. Try again please!");

        });

        });
</script>
```

My controller looks like this

```
public function change_doctor_status(Request $request)
{


   $id = $request['doctor_id'];
   $status = $request['status'];
   if($status==1)
   {
      $query=DB::table('doctors')->where('id',$id)->update(['status' => 0]);
      if($query)
      {
        return true;
      }

   }
   else if($status==0)
   {
     $query=DB::table('doctors')->where('id',$id)->update(['status' => 1]);
      if($query)
      {
        return true;
      }
   }
}
```

i had routed it like this

```
Route::post('/change-doctor-status', 'Admin\AdminController@change_doctor_status');
```

here when i go for the result am always getting like this alert("There was an error. Try again please!"); which is stored in the fail section

Comment: All the post requests to laravel should have the csrf_token to eliminate cross site request forgery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing this in blade file

```
$.post(url, {doctor_id:doctor_id,status:status }).done(function (result) {
               alert("success");
            }).fail(function(result) {
              alert("There was an error. Try again please!");
```

Add one more line.

```
$.post(url, {doctor_id:doctor_id,status:status,_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}' }).done(function (result) {
               alert("success");
            }).fail(function(result) {
              alert("There was an error. Try again please!");
```

Comment: thanks i had used your code but its not getting success

Comment: Can you check and tell me what you get using network tab of your browser

Comment: but when i changed your code like this i got the previous error ` $.post(url, {doctor_id:doctor_id,status:status,_token:_token }).done(function (result) {` i had placed _token like this `var _token= $('input[name="_token"]').val();` while using this am getting that error

Comment: Can you tell me what you are getting in responce

Comment: while using your code am not getting anything on network tab

Comment: Ok what is the response you are getting from server?

Comment: getting like this `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString()`

Comment: replace true with 'true'  you cannot return boolean values you should return string so add quotes around true and false